# $u_{xx}u_{yy} - u_{xy}u_{yx} \le 0$ for an entire complex function $f=u+iv$

Tags: complex-analysis

Im trying to prove that $u_{xx}u_{yy} - u_{xy}u_{yx} \le 0$ and that this l.h.s is the same value even when $u$ is changed to $v$.

But I don't know how to approach. I tried to use cauchy-riemann equation but it didn't help. Can you guys give me some hint?

**EDIT**

notations regarding $u$'s mean partial derivative with respect to real($x$) and imaginary($y$) parts.

Comment: i'm guessing you mean $f$ is an analytic function, also can you explain your notation with the $u$'s

Comment: @john yeah you're right. I changed title. Also notations regarding $u$'s mean partial derivative with respect to real($x$) and imaginary($y$) parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Cauchy-Riemann equations and  [Schwarz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz's_theorem) on the symmetry of second derivatives we have:
$$
u_{xx} = (u_x)_x = (v_y)_x = (v_x)_y = (-u_y)_y = -u_{yy}
$$
which is the known fact that the real (and imaginary) part of an analytic function is *harmonic.* It follows that
$$
u_{xx}u_{yy} - u_{xy}u_{yx} = -u_{xx}^2 - u_{xy}^2 \le 0 \, .
$$
Also
$$
u_{xx}u_{yy} - u_{xy}u_{yx} = (-v_y)_x (v_x)_y - (v_y)_y (-v_x)_x = 
v_{xx}v_{yy} - v_{xy}v_{yx} \, .
$$

Comment: Is there a way of showing $(v_y)_x=(v_x)_y$ using more elementary facts not relying on schwarz's theorem?(don't need to be general, it is enough to be applicable to this specific case) Because my class seems not have covered it yet. Or is it the easiest way?

Comment: @queueoverflow: This is the easiest way, I am currently not aware of an alternative proof.